# Need hint: Determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^{n^2}$ is convergent or divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^{n^2}$ is convergent or divergent.

I've tried applying all the basic tests to no avail. I need to find out what the "trick" for this particular series is.

Comment: did you try the divergence test?

Comment: @JavaMan Does this hint help? That sequence goes to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: @F'OlaYinka - Are you sure? It doesn't seem to me that your inequality holds for $n\geq{3}$. You want to say that $\frac{2}{3}\leq{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: @B.D. Thanks for the comment.  I misread the sequence as $a_n = \left( \frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}$ for some reason.

Comment: @ Ittay Weiss: the Divergence Test fails since the expression tends to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the following:
$$\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^{n}=\Big(\frac{m-1}{m}\Big)^{m-1}=(1-1/m)^{m-1}$$
That formula/function seems familiar, doesn't it?

Thereafter, note that:
$$\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^{n^{2}}={\Big(\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^{n}\space\Big)}^{n}$$
**Hint**: Simple comparison test with a sequence you know well.

Comment: Oh, snap - that was the "trick" I was looking for. Thanks, Much appreciated.

Comment: Nah, you could have used the root method. I just feel this is a lot more elegant.

Answer (score 5):

Let $u_n$ = $ \Big ( \frac {n}{n+1} \Big)^{n^2}$ , then since $ \ \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{({\frac{n}{n+1}})^{n^2}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^n = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}})^n$ = $\frac1e$ $ < 1 $ , so by Cauchy's root test the series  is convergent .

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try with [Cauchy's root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test).

Comment: $\displaystyle \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ does *not* approach $1$ as $n\to\infty$. For one thing, directly expanding it gives that $\displaystyle \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\ge 1+n\left(\frac1n\right)=2$.

Comment: @ Seeker : The limit is $\frac 1e $ $<1$ , so Cauchy's root test in fact proves the covergence

Comment: Ah, lesson learned. Thanks all!